# My parse StartTime and EndTime does not connect with my app correctly. Help? (Java)

Tags: java, android, parsing

I have developed a Booking App and the back end for the app is through Parse. For some reason the updated information in Parse is totally different from what comes up in the app when it is ran through the emulator. For e.g. my StartTime(Date) is April 14, 2015, 19:00 and my EndTime(Date) is April 14, 2015, 20:00. Yet when I run the app the event is on a different date and time. Can someone help me?

```
    private void makeWebCallToParse() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GymSession");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null) {
                for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                    WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent();
                    event.setName(objects.get(i).getString("GymSession"));
                    event.setId(i);

                    event.setParseObjectId(objects.get(i).getObjectId());

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, objects.get(i).getDate("StartTime").getDay());
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, objects.get(i).getDate("StartTime").getMonth());
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, objects.get(i).getDate("StartTime").getYear());
                    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, objects.get(i).getDate("StartTime").getMinutes());
                    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, objects.get(i).getDate("StartTime").getHours());
                    event.setStartTime(cal);

                    Calendar calEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calEnd.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, objects.get(i).getDate("EndTime").getDay());
                    calEnd.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, objects.get(i).getDate("EndTime").getMonth());
                    calEnd.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, objects.get(i).getDate("EndTime").getYear());
                    calEnd.set(Calendar.MINUTE, objects.get(i).getDate("EndTime").getMinutes());
                    calEnd.set(Calendar.HOUR, objects.get(i).getDate("EndTime").getHours());
                    event.setEndTime(calEnd);

                    event.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.event_color_01));
                    eventsWeb.add(event);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use beforeSave cloud method to match up time.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("YourClassName", function(request, response) { 
     request.object.set("yourDateField", new Date()); 
     response.success(); 
});
```

This will set "yourDateField" with the server time stamp (GMT) before inserting the row into the Class.

More details: [parse cloud code guide](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-onsave)